# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard importing with wrong characters - Code page

Tags: sql, ssms

I use SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to import CSV and Excel files to my DB. After successfully importing the files I found special characters in some cells were replaced by '??'. Probably because I selected the wrong 'Code page' setting.

Some special characters 'é', 'à' and 'è' that were replaced by '??'.

**PROBLEM**

After importing value ***Danièle*** from CSV, it becomes ***Dani??le*** in the DB.

**ATTEMPTS**

I tried to fix this by changing the 'Code page', but I can try all values all day long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MY SOLUTION/WORKAROUND:**

1. I opened the CSV in Excel and saved it as an Excel sheet (.xls)
2. Finally imported it using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, and set the Code Page to UTF-8